# Sorting Information in an array by weeks

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, sorting

I have an array of dates like

```
array
1 => string '2012-02-27' (length=10)
2 => string '2012-03-02' (length=10)
59 => string '2012-03-05' (length=10)
```

and so on. These dates represent days that people applied for something. For example, on February 27, 3 people applied and on March 1st 2.

What I want to do is create a table that says on the week of `2012-02-26` to `2012-03-03` 5 people submitted an application. The left hand column's title would be `Weeks` and the right hand column's would be `# of applications received`.

I already have the table set up by day but weeks would be helpful too. I had seen a post talking about listing weeks and tried using that but it didn't work.

More specifically my question is how do I take an array of dates and break them up by weeks and put that information in a table?

Comment: a) You need to post your code (I see you're new, so you get some baby protection) and b) please make your specific problem more clear, what is the road blocker? Please read: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and then improve your question by editing it.

Comment: Not exactly. The keys are the id of people.

Comment: For example Bob is the 1st person to apply on the 27th then Sue would be someone applying on March 2nd. Then George would be number 3 applying also on March 2nd

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what database engine you were using, but most have a date format field "week of year", so `SELECT COUNT, YEAR(date), WEEKOFYEAR(date) FROM stuff GROUP BY YEAR(date), WEEKOFYEAR(date)`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this in php, not a DB.

```
1) convert dates to epoch (seconds) with strtotime()
2) sort array by (numeric now) date with asort()
3) loop through the sorted now array from start date to end date and add the values.
```

Of course that could be done much easier with a database.